# Using Nodejs to stream GIF count down timer to client

Tags: node.js, email

I need a countdown timer in my email. The only way I know it's possible is to use the img element and point to a server in my src attribute that returns a stream of say GIF encoded data. I went ahead and built it out and most of it works. However, when the timer updates, I am not seeing the changes being consumed in my stream. Please help!

My code is here: https://github.com/ElijahCannon/email-countdown.git

I think I'm not understanding something in the timer.js update() method, do I use canvasStream.on with events, or do I use pipe? I wasn't able to get as far just using pipe(), but maybe that's because I'm using the wrong stream types? My temporary stream (created every update) is a readableStream (https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas#canvascreatepngstream), and my main stream piped to res is a duplex stream.

Any insight you can provide would be very helpful. Streams are a very confusing topic for me.

Comment: A client dont update the image just because you changed the content

Comment: Then what is this? https://cdn.countdownmail.com/images/timers/home/12.gif

Comment: There are lots of companies who do just this and then they sell it to email marketers. Like this: https://countdownmail.com/

Comment: Perhaps read your own link next time, its a gif and not a png. The gif can only display a certian time span, e.g. 1h, then the client must make a new request. If your client has the email long enough open the "video" starts playing from the start again. There is no way to tell the client "do another request for that media file" Look at the demo gif: http://i.countdownmail.com/td.gif This is only one minute long. Afther that, the animations start from scratch. Play with it here: https://onlinegiftools.com/analyze-gif

Comment: I meant GIF from the start. But even then, you can stream endlessly. I know for a fact that you can.